# Why does IE (11) spontaneously wipe the localstorage in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, cookies, local-storage

I have an application with reactjs that has a login page and after the user logon successfully i save the token in localstorge and save a cookie in my browser , it works well in all browsers except IE (11) , i trace that after logon the IE clear localstorage again and then user returns to login page ; i really don't know what to do :(

it's my login component :

```js
export default function Login(props){


    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        Username : '' , 
        Password : '' ,
        Remember : false , 
        error : false
    });
    const loginBtn = React.createRef();
    const [token , setToken] = useState(null);
    const [output , setOutput] = useState(null);

    const handleChange = name => event => {
       // console.log(name);
        setValues({
            ...values , 
            [name] : event.target.value
        });        
    };

    console.log('cookie (out): ' , document.cookie);
    console.log('localstorage (out): ' , localStorage.getItem('access_Token'));

    const loginClick = () => {
        axios.post('/dashboard/auth' , {"username" : values.Username , "password" : values.Password})
            .then(response => {
                localStorage.setItem('access_Token' , response.data.access_Token);
                document.cookie = 'electiondashboard=1';
                setOutput(<Redirect to='/dashboard' />);
                console.log('cookie : ' , document.cookie);
                console.log('localstorage : ' , localStorage.getItem('access_Token'));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('in login : ' , error);
                setValues({
                    ...values ,
                    error : true
                });
            });

    };

    const onKeyDownhandler = (e) => {
        if(e.keyCode === 13){
            e.preventDefault();
            loginBtn.current.click();
        }
    };


    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className={myClasses.DRT_Login}>
                <div className={myClasses.DRT_Box}>
                    <h4 className={myClasses.DRT_Title}>
                        به سامانه انتخاباتی دورتال
                        <br/>
                        خوش آمدید
                    </h4>
                    <form>
                        <div>
                            <label>
                                ایمیل یا نام کاربری خود را وارد کنید 
                            </label>
                            <input type='text' name='Username'
                                    placeholder='Enter Username Or Email Address'
                                    onChange={handleChange('Username')} 
                                    onKeyDown={e => onKeyDownhandler(e)}/>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>رمز ورود را وارد کنید</label>
                            <input type='password' name='Password'
                                    placeholder='Enter Password'
                                    onChange={handleChange('Password')} 
                                    onKeyDown={e => onKeyDownhandler(e)}/>
                        </div>
                        <Grid container>
                            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                                <a href="http://google.com" className={myClasses.DRT_ForgotPass}>
                                    رمز عبور خود را فراموش کرده اید ؟
                                </a>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <div>
                            <ButtonTemp 
                                    type='link' 
                                    mode='primary' 
                                    styles={{width : '100%' , fontWeight : 'normal' , marginTop : '20px'}}
                                    onclick={loginClick}
                                    reactRef={loginBtn}>
                                ورود
                            </ButtonTemp>
                        </div>
                        {
                            values.error ? 
                                (<AlertTemp type='danger' styles={{fontSize : '13px'}}>
                                    نام کاربری یا رمز عبور اشتباه است
                                </AlertTemp>) : ''
                        }
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>

            {output}
        </Fragment>


    );

};
```

and it's my index component that checks the token then directs the user when can go :

```js
export default function Index(props){

    const [token , setToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem('access_Token'));

    console.log('in index localstorage : ' , localStorage.getItem('access_Token'));
    console.log('in index localstorage eeeee : ' , (localStorage.getItem('access_Token') === null) );

    useEffect(() => {
        if(localStorage.getItem('access_Token'))
            setToken(localStorage.getItem('access_Token'));
        else
            setToken(null);
    } , [token]);


    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Layout} />
            <Route exact path='/dashboard/cartable' component={Layout} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/cartable/requests' component={Layout} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/cartable/approved' component={Layout} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/cartable/rejected' component={Layout} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/elections-management' component={Layout} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/statistics/assignee' component={Layout} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/statistics/participation' component={Layout} />
            <Route path='/dashboard/errors' component={Layout} />
            {
                token === null ? 
                    <Route path='/dashboard/login' component={Login} /> 
                    : <Redirect to='/dashboard' />
            }
        </Fragment>
    );

};
```

Comment: Try to test [this sample](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_local_clickcount) on your IE browser, if the local storage still doesn't work well, it means that issue is related to the IE browser, try to reset the IE browser setting or reinstall the IE browser. If the local storage works well, perhaps the issue is related your code, please try to add some debugger in your code or using F12 developer tools to debug your code and check the local storage (whether you are using the clear method to clear the local storage).

Comment: thanks for your help , i'll try it

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is your is because as you said you are ok in other browsers, I suggest if you are not using win 10 update your ie 
I hope it works for you

-Update: I meant the only problem is IE, not other browsers so you need to update your ie because maybe the problem reason is your ie is outdated

Comment: Unfortunately it's not only my browser's problem because i test that i other systems ie